# Catching the "Views nested within a <Text> must have a width and height" error

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-htmlview](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview) in a react-native application to render some received arbitrary HTML (GitHub transformed markdown).
In some case, I get the following runtime error:

> Views nested within a <Text> must have a width and height

This is usually the case when I didn't implement my own rendering for a specific HTML tag, or some specific tags combination.

I tried to leverage the new `componentDidCatch()` lifecycle method introduced in react 16.0.0 / react-native 0.49.x, but this method doesn't seem to be called at all when this error occur. (Using 16.0.0/0.50.3).

Is there any know way to catch this error in order to display a nicely designed error message and avoid the crash?

Comment: Very interesting problem, and great question. Any idea why the error boundary isn't being triggered? Have you made sure that your error boundary is working for other errors? Are you able to setup a demo of this that we can play with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in React Native 0.54+:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18491

Comment: looking at the link, it seems that RN team closed it as 'not a bug'.  Basically the above error considered a "native" error, and RN's intenral handlers will *not* invoke any of the React's error lifecycle methods.

Comment: Still seeing this error in "react-native": "0.61.4" Specifically Android, not iOS